# Detect on Windows PC if Video is being played

Tags: windows, video, c#

Video being played could be using any media player(e.g. WMP, VLC etc) or online streamed through any browser.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: what exactly should that software do? How much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions? Please **[edit]** your question and include those details. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.